# Win32: What is HRESULT 0x80070002?

Tags: winapi, hresult

I can't find the definition of HRESULT: 0x80070002

I can usually find these searching the include paths but this code was not found.  Does anyone have the explanation of what it is?  I think it is coming from the shell.

Thanks.

Comment: This free online tool can help https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0x80070002 (disclaimer, I wrote it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x80070002` is the Win32 error code 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`) in `HRESULT` format, as returned by the [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-hresult_from_win32) macro.

When in doubt, you can use the [`HRESULT_FACILITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-hresult_facility) and [`HRESULT_CODE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-hresult_code) macros to help you figure out what an `HRESULT` stands for.

In this case, `0x80070002` has a facility of 7 (`FACILITY_WIN32`), meaning the code (2) is a Win32 error code (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`).

Answer (score 1):

errlook.exe says it is "The system cannot find the file specified." , agreed that it is not in any of the SDK (or VS2019) headers.

Answer (score -1):

Removing and adding the service(WebSite) back in IIS fixed the error for me.
It might have been the case of the service path being incorrect since it was last added in IIS.

Make sure you're passing the correct physical path to IIS when adding the a web site.